# Java Service Wrapper server socket creation failed

Tags: java, sockets, jboss, wrapper, windows-7-x64

I need help.

I am running java service wrapper and get error:

```
ERROR  | wrapperp | 2013/07/23 15:18:08 | server socket creation failed. (An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726))
```

How i can solve this problem?

[image]

Configuration file
http://pastebin.com/LHDpw6WQ

windows 7 64 bit, jdk 7

Answer (score 0):

*An invalid argument was supplied.*

That is your answer - check the values you are using to create/open the socket. One of those values is *invalid*.

Without knowing exactly how your socket code looks and what values you are using, I can't help any more than that...

Comment: The same configuration and code work on another machine good.

Comment: Again, you need to look at the _arguments supplied_, those might be okay for another machine, but obviously not the one you're having troubles on...

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to use a newer version of the Wrapper?  That one is VERY old and the code has been reworked a bit over the years.

I would also need to see your configuration file to see what you are doing to cause this to happen.

Cheers,
Leif

Comment: I added link to conf file. Changing is not possible, i using open source project (RHQ).